# Display Custom Label from data store with dojox.charting

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

I am using the `dojox.charting.widget.Chart2D` and I am trying to retrieve the data from an `dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore`.  I can retrieve the data, and everything works and displays, except I cannot seem to find a way to display custom labels on the items.  My HTML snippet is:

```
<div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" jsId="chartDataStore" 
    url="json/archiveinfo.json.php"></div>
<div dojoType="dojox.charting.widget.Chart2D" id="chartTest" 
    theme="dojox.charting.themes.PlotKit.blue" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
  <div class="plot" name="default" type="Pie" fontColor="black" htmlLabels="false" 
    radius="100"></div>
  <div class="series" name="Series A" store="chartDataStore" field="y" 
    label="text" valueFn="Number(x)"></div>
  <div class="action" type="Tooltip"></div>
  <div class="action" type="MoveSlice"></div>
</div>
```

And my JSON from the ItemFileReadStore is:

```
{"identifier":"id","labelAttribute":"text","items":
  [
    {"id":1,"y":55,"text":"Free"},
    {"id":2,"y":45,"text":"Used"}
  ]
}
```

I have tried setting the label attribute in the series and have set the `labelAttribute` in the JSON.  I also tried just `label` in the JSON and it didn't work either.  When I provide the data as a JSON in an `array` or provide the `data` directly in the series, I get the labels to work.  I really wanted to make it more flexible though by providing the data via a DataStore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it is to modify your JSON a little and update corresponding attributes in the HTML.

JSON:

```
{
  "items": [
    {"id":1, "slice": {"y":55,"text":"Free"}},
    {"id":2, "slice": {"y":45,"text":"Used"}}
  ]
}
```

The only meaningful change is to separate pie-specific data in a sub-object (`slice`) for simplicity.

HTML (only the store-related line should be modified):

```
<div class="series" name="Series A"
  store="chartDataStore" field="slice"></div>
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.  I am generating the JSON as per your suggestion and I have set the `field="slice"` but the chart does not render and I don't get any errors in Firebug.  I tried changing the `label="slice.text"` and the `valueFn="Number(x.y)"` thinking maybe I needed to access them as objects, but still no luck.  I reverted back to just make sure I didn't make any mistakes and it start working as before.

Comment: No need to mess with `label` or `valueFn`, or anything else. It looks like I forgot to remove `identifier`. You can remove `id` as well to keep your data cleaner.

I actually recreated your example, and it works for me now.

Answer (score -1):

I had to face similar trouble with custom labels, although I was using a programmatic way to create the chart on div.... Hope this helps someone....

```
var mytooltip = new dojox.charting.action2d.Tooltip(mychart,"default", 
    {text: function(e) {
               var tooltiptext = <construct ur custom label here>   
               return tooltiptext;
        }
    });
```

`mychart` is the variable that i have used to create the chart widget....